# R: Difference between as.dist( ) and dist( )

Tags: r

What is the difference between `as.dist( )` and `dist( )`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`dist()` will actually calculate the distance matrix whereas `as.dist()` only will try to coerce a object to a distance matrix.

Comment: granted it's not within the expected scope of the answer, when should I one over another? i.e. when should I use as.dist?

Comment: @dhfromkorea use 'dist()' when you have to calculate the distance matrix and 'as.dist()' when the distances are already there but in another class ('vector', 'data.frame', etc)

Comment: @dhfromkorea you will have the distances (as @Luciano Selzer mentioned "are  already there") most often by the explicit calculation:  `1 - cor(t(data))`